# how server responds in multi tab browsing

Tags: networking, network-programming

When we use multi tab in a browser how the server response to that particular tab which requested the page. How server knows which tab it needs to respond.

Comment: The Server does not know. If you want to distignuish between the tabs you must care for it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The server doesn't respond to tabs. It responds to HTTP requests. The response is sent back down the same connection the request came over. Mapping connections to tabs is the brower's problem.

Comment: How browser maps connection to tabs

Comment: Any way it likes. Depends on the browser. You can think in terms of a connection-per-tab model but under the hood it is far more likely to be a connection pooling system.